# weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.Entity is not visible from class loader

Tags: hibernate, java-8, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

On deploying EJB application on weblogic 12c , I am getting exception :-

```
"weblogic.management.DeploymentException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.Entity is 
not visible from class loader"
```

Below is the configuration in weblogic-application.xml

```
<prefer-application-packages>
<package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
```

Have placed the following jars in WL_DOMAIN/lib

```
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final 
com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1
hibernate
dom4j
javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2
```

I am unable to understand why is this exception occuring.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did u fount solution?